# JavaScript: How to use (backtick) ` in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, how do you use use the backtick (`) in a regular expression?

Sample code:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9àâçéèêîïôùû-.,:+*'()=&_ \s\u0060]+$/
```

Comment: Works for me. <code>/\`/.test('foo`bar') === true && /\`/.test('foobar') === false</code>

Comment: Backtick has no special meaning in regular expressions, you don't need to escape it.

Comment: Show us what you tried, the results you got, and what you expected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

backtick has no special meaning. you can use it as `` /`/ ``, it will work fine.

Comment: What about the new [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @daka Doesn't change anything. Still no special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: If you want to use template literal backticks in a regular expression see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390873/template-literal-inside-of-the-regex. In short use new RegExp('regexp') instead of /regexp/

Answer (score 4):

Use unicode character searches and it should do it. Unicode character code for backtick is `\u0060`

So `/\u0060/` should find you backticks. Tested it on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) and it works.

However, as previous respondent correctly said, ` should just work fine without escaping. You must have the problem somewhere else if it doesn't. But using the unicode will ensure that it will definitely match.

Comment: and Srb1313711, this is my regex /^[a-zA-Z0-9àâçéèêîïôùû-.,:+*'()=&_ \s]+$/

i have a text box where i can create a record here its not accepting backtick, i am not allowed to enter backtick, it shows red mark.

Comment: @RajasekharP I just test your regex with [JS Regex Tester](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and it's fine it works. if you can't enter backticks to the textbox, then the unicode character should do the job.

Comment: can you please edit my regex dat fits with unicode character.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9àâçéèêîïôùû-.,:+*'()=&_ \s\u0060]+$/

Comment: just make sure that the textbox you're entering your regex in accepts regex in that format. some of them don't expect you to include the delimeters (//), just the regex plain.

Comment: so in that case, you'll enter `^[a-zA-Z0-9àâçéèêîïôùû-.,:+*'()=&_ \s\u0060]+$` ONLY, without opening and closing delimeters

Comment: still it does nor works :(, to be more clear, its EXTJS

    xtype: 'textfield',
    regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9àâçéèêîïôùû-.,:+*'()=&_ \s\u0060]+$/

i have tried both ways with and with out delimeters (//).

Comment: @RajasekharP I know nothing about ExtJS but have you tried enclosing your regex in quotes? so xtype: 'textfield', regex:'<rgex>'

Comment: sorry, can't be of any more help :(

Answer (score 1):

I dont actually think that this character needs escaping, look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for the characters that need escaping

You can also try [here](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php#sourcetab) to test which I find very helpful.