# Template literal inside of the RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, template-literals

I tried to place a template literal inside of a RegEx, and it didn't work. I then made a variable `regex` which holds my RegEx, but it still not giving me the desired result.

However if I `console.log(regex)` individually, I do receive the desired RegEx, such as `/.+?(?=location)/i`, `/.+?(?=date)/i` and so on, but once I place `regex` inside the `.replace` it appears not to be working

```
function validate (data) {
  let testArr = Object.keys(data);
  errorMessages.forEach((elem, i) => {
    const regex = `/.+?(?=${elem.value})/i`;
    const a = testArr[i].replace(regex, '');
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Your `regex` variable is a *String*. To make it a RegExp, use a `RegExp` constructor:

```
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`pattern_as_in_regex_literal_without_delimiters`)
```

For example, a regex literal like `/<\d+>/g` can be re-written as

```
const re = RegExp(String.raw`<\d+>`, 'g') // One \ is a literal backslash
const re = RegExp(`<\\d+>`, 'g')       // Two \ are required in a non-raw string literal
```

To insert a variable you may use

```
const digits = String.raw`\d+`;
const re = RegExp(`<${digits}>`, 'g')
```

To solve your issue, you may use

```
const regex = new RegExp(`.+?(?=${elemvalue.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})`, "i");
```

Also, it is a good idea to [escape the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) part in the regex so as all special regex metacharacters were treated as literals.

```js
const s = "final (location)";
const elemvalue = "(location)";
const regex = new RegExp(`.+?(?=${elemvalue.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')})`, "i");
// console.log(regex); // /.+?(?=\(location\))/i
// console.log(typeof(regex)); // object
let a = s.replace(regex, '');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: What is this `String.raw` thing?

Comment: @MarcosPereira JavaScript syntax used to define taw string literals.

Answer (score -5):

> A more advanced form of template literals are *[Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)*. - MDN

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

const regex = ({ // (1)
  raw: [part, ...parts]
}, ...subs) => new RegExp(
  subs.reduce( // (2)
    (result, sub, i) => `${result}${escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
    part
  )
);


const t1 = `d`;
const r1 = regex `^ab(c${t1}e)`;  // (3) 
// /^ab(cde)/
console.log('r2.test(`abc${t1}e`); ➜', r1.test(`abc${t1}e`)); // true

// Check for proper escaped special chars
const t2 = `(:?bar)\d{2}`;
const r2 = regex `foo${t2}`; 
// /foo\(:\?bar\)d\{2\}/  ➜ t2 is escaped!

console.log('r2.test(`foo${t2}`); ➜', r2.test(`foo${t2}`)); // true
console.log('r2.test(`foo\(:\?bar\)d\{2\}`); ➜', r2.test(`foo\(:\?bar\)d\{2\}`)); // true
console.log('r2.test(`foobar11`); ➜', r2.test(`foobar11`)); // false
console.log(r2);
```

### How it works:

1. Define a "tag function" (name does not matter) e.g. `regex()` to build our regular expression (`return new RegExp()`) from a **template literal string**.

   > Hint: Tag functions don't even need to return a string!

   - **First** param `parts` is a `string[]` (segments between injected vars).

     `a${..}bc${..}de` ➜ `['a', 'bc', 'de'] = parts`

     > Hint: The **special** `raw` property, available on the **first** argument to the tag function, allows you to access the raw strings as they were entered, without processing escape sequences.

     This is what we need! We can destructure the **first** param, and split out the first `part` of `parts`. This is our first regExp `result` segment.
   - **`subs...`** are **substitution** values from injected vars:

     `..${'x'}..${'y'}..` ➜ `['x', 'y']`
2. **Loop** over `...subs` and concatenate regex **string**:

   1. `escape()` special chars from current `stubs[i]` (which would break the final expression).
   2. Append **escaped** `stubs[i]` and add `parts[i]` in between.
3. Prefix a *template literal* string, with `` regex `...` ``  and a new `RegExp` is returned:

   `` const r1 = regex `^ab(c${t1}e)` ``  ➜ `/^ab(cde)/`

---

### Conditional escape

So far, `regex()` handles all template vars `..${..}..${..}..` as strings. (invoke `.toString()`)

```
regex `X${new Date()}X`          // /X7\.12\.2020X/
regex `X${{}}X`                  // /X\[object Object\]X/
regex `X${[1, 'b', () => 'c']}X` // /X1,b,\(\) => 'c'X/
```

Even though this is the intended behavior, we can not use it in all places.

**How to concat regular expressions in "tagged templates?**

> Use case: You want a 'RegExp factory class' to build more complex expressions from smaller pieces.
> E.g. a RegExp to parse/validate [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) header values for *javascript-like* [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#JavaScript_types). syntax: `media-type = type "/" subtype`.
> This is what we want to find:
>
> - `*/*`
> - `application/*`, `application/javascript`,  `application/ecmascript`,
> - `text/*`, `text/javascript`, `text/ecmascript`

```
const group = (name, regExp) => regex`(?<${name}>${regExp})`;

const rTypeGroup = group(`type`, `(text|application|\*)+?`);  
// /(?<type>\(text\|application\|\*\)\+\?)/ 
const rSubGroup = group(`sub`, `((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?`); 
// /(?<sub>\(\(java\|ecma\)\+\?script\|\*\)\+\?)/
// .. and test
rTypeGroup.test(`application`);                   // false !!!
rTypeGroup.test(`\(text\|application\|\*\)\+\?`); // true !!!
```

Since `regex()` escapes all substitutions, the bodies of our capture groups matche literally. We can modify `regex()` and skip `escape()` for some types. Now we can pass RegEx instances and skip `escape()`.

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
const regex = ({
  raw: [part, ...parts]
}, ...subs) => new RegExp( //            skip escape()
  subs.reduce( //                   ┏━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┓ 
    (result, sub, i) => `${result}${sub instanceof RegExp ? sub.source : escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
    part
  )
);

const group = (name, regExp) => regex `(?<${name}>${regExp})`;

//                                         RegEx
//                               ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┓               
const rTypeGroup = group(`type`, /(text|application|\*)+?/); //  /(?<type>(text|application|\*)+?)/
const rSubGroup = group(`sub`, /((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?/); // /(?<sub>((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?)/

// Type
console.log('rTypeGroup.test(`*`); ➜', rTypeGroup.test(`*`)); // true
console.log('rTypeGroup.test(`text`); ➜', rTypeGroup.test(`text`)); // true

console.log('rTypeGroup.exec(`*`).groups.type; ➜', rTypeGroup.exec(`*`).groups.type); // '*'
console.log('rTypeGroup.exec(`text`).groups.type; ➜', rTypeGroup.exec(`text`).groups.type); // 'text'

// SubType
console.log('rSubGroup.test(`*`); ➜', rSubGroup.test(`*`)); // true
console.log('rSubGroup.test(`javascript`); ➜', rSubGroup.test(`javascript`)); // true
console.log('rSubGroup.test(`ecmascript`); ➜', rSubGroup.test(`ecmascript`)); // true

console.log('rSubGroup.exec(`*`).groups.sub; ➜', rSubGroup.exec(`*`).groups.sub); // '*'
console.log('rSubGroup.exec(`javascript`).groups.sub; ➜', rSubGroup.exec(`javascript`).groups.sub); // 'javascript'
```

We can now decide whether a var should be escaped, or not. Since we have ignored any quantifiers and flags, our groups also validate `ABCtextDEF`, `12texttext`,... .

Now we can bundle multiple RegEx:

```
//                                                 '/' would be escaped! RegEx needed..            
//                                                               ┏━┻━┓
const rMediaTypeGroup = group(`mediaType`, regex `${rTypeGroup}${/\//}${rSubGroup}`);
// /(?<mediaType>(?<type>(text|application|\*)+?)\/(?<sub>((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?))/
rMediaTypeGroup.test(`text/javascript`)); // true
```

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
const regex = ({
  raw: [part, ...parts]
}, ...subs) => new RegExp(
  subs.reduce(
    (result, sub, i) => `${result}${sub instanceof RegExp ? sub.source : escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
    part
  )
);

const group = (name, regExp) => regex `(?<${name}>${regExp})`;
const rTypeGroup = group(`type`, /(text|application|\*)+?/);
const rSubGroup = group(`sub`, /((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?/);

//                                                 '/' would be escaped! RegEx needed..            
//                                                               ┏━┻━┓
const rMediaTypeGroup = group(`mediaType`, regex `${rTypeGroup}${/\//}${rSubGroup}`);
// /(?<mediaType>(?<type>(text|application|\*)+?)\/(?<sub>((java|ecma)+?script|\*)+?))/

console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`*/*`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`*/*`)); // true
console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`**/**`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`**/**`)); // true
console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`text/javascript`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`text/javascript`)); // true

console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`1text/javascriptX`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`1text/javascriptX`)); // true
console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`*/java`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`*/java`)); // true

console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`text/X`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`text/X`)); // false
console.log('rMediaTypeGroup.test(`/*`); ➜', rMediaTypeGroup.test(`/*`)); // false
```

---

### Flags

All flags must be known before initialization. You can read them (`/xx/gm.flags`, `/xx/gm.multiline`, `/xx/i.ignoreCase`,..) but there are no setters.

> A tagged template function (e.g. `regex()`) returning `new Regex()` needs to know all flags.

This section demonstrates 3 alternatives of how to handle flags.

- Option A: Pass flags as `${templateVariable}` ➜ Not recommendet!
- Option B: Extend `class RegExp`
- Option C: Use `Proxy()` for flags

#### Option A: Pass flags as `${templateVariable}`. ➜ Not recommendet!

Thread flags like other substitution vars. We need to check if last variable is *flag-like* (`g`, `mi`,..) and split it away from `subs`...

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

const regex = ({
  raw: [part, ...parts],
  // super verbose...
  splitFlags = ({ // destruct subs[] Array (arrays are objects!)
    length: l,    // destruct subs[].length to l
    iEnd = l - 1, // last array index to iEnd
    [iEnd]: sub,  // subs[subs.length - i] to sub
    ...subs       // subs[0...n-1] to subs
  }) => [         // returns RegEx() constr. params: [flags, concat regex string]                                                    
    //             ┏━━━━━━━━ all chars of sub flag-like? ━━━━━━━━━┓   ┏━ flags  ┏━ re-add last sub and set flags: undefined
    [...sub].every(f => ['s', 'g', 'i', 'm', 'y', 'u'].includes(f)) ? sub : !(subs[iEnd] = sub) || undefined,
    Object.values(subs).reduce( // concat regex string
      (result, sub, i) => `${result}${escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
      part
    )
  ]
}, ...subs) => new RegExp(...splitFlags(subs).reverse());

const r1 = regex `^foo(${`bar`})${'i'}`;
console.log('r1:', r1, 'flags:', r1.flags); // /^foo(bar)/i    ['i' flag]

const r2 = regex `^foo(${`bar`})${'mgi'}`;
console.log('r2:', r2, 'flags:', r2.flags); // /^foo(bar)/gim  ['gim' flag]

//            invalid flag 'x' ━━━━┓
const r3 = regex `^foo(${`bar`})${'x'}`;
console.log('r3:', r3, 'flags:', r3.flags); // /^foo(bar)x/    [no flags]

//              invalid flag 'z' ━━━━┓
const r4 = regex `^foo(${`bar`})${'gyzu'}`;
console.log('r4:', r4, 'flags:', r4.flags); // /^foo(bar)gyzu/ [no flags]
```

Code looks super verbose and mixing up **flag-logic** and **substitution-logic** is not obvious from outside. It will also break the final regex if last variable is falsely determine as *flag-like*.

> We look for phone types, like `i-phone`, `a-phone`,...

```
const rPhoneA = regex `${`a`}-phone`; // 
console.log('rPhoneA:', rPhoneA, 'flags:', rPhoneA.flags); // /a-phone/     [no flags]
const rPhoneI = regex `${`i`}-phone`; 
console.log('rPhoneI:', rPhoneI, 'flags:', rPhoneI.flags); // /(?:)/i       ['i' flag]

console.log('rPhoneA.test(`a-phone`); ➜', rPhoneA.test(`a-phone`)); // true
console.log('rPhoneA.test(`i-phone`); ➜', rPhoneA.test(`i-phone`)); // false

console.log('rPhoneI.test(`a-phone`); ➜', rPhoneI.test(`a-phone`)); // true
console.log('rPhoneI.test(`i-phone`); ➜', rPhoneI.test(`i-phone`)); // true
```

... all phones are `i-phones`! Because `i` is a **flag-like** substituion and is removed from `subs...` array which is now empty `[]`. `reduce()` returns an empty string `''` and `new RegExp('', 'i')` adds an empty non-capture group: `(?:)`.

#### Option B: Extend `class RegExp`

We can extend from `RegExp` and add **getter** methods to set flags. Make them **self-returning** so we can chain them. We can even add a `_` "clear flags" method.

This works nice, but also has the effect, that each flag added/removed, results in a new clone of `TRegExp`. If we build "static" (cachable) expressions it is probably OK for you.

- A: Add **getters** in the constructor inside a loop. Or..
- B: Add class **getters**

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

class TRegExp extends RegExp {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    // Clear all flags
    Object.defineProperty(this, '_', {
      get() {
        return this.flags.length ? new TRegExp(this.source) : this;
      },
      enumerable: false
    });

    // A: define getters for all flags  
    ['g', 'i', 'm', 'u', 'y'].reduce((my, flag) => Object.defineProperty(my, flag, {
      get() {    // clone this on flags change ━━┓
        return my.flags.includes(flag) ? my : new TRegExp(my.source, `${my.flags}${flag}`);
      }, //                 return this ━━┛
      enumerable: false
    }), this);
  }

  // B: Define getters for each flag individually
  // get g() {
  //     return this.flags.includes('g') ? this : new TRegExp(this.source, `${this.flags}g`);
  // }
}

const regex = ({raw: [part, ...parts]}, ...subs) => new TRegExp(
  subs.reduce( //                                       ┣━━ TRegExp()
    (result, sub, i) => `${result}${subs instanceof TRegExp ? sub.source : escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
    part
  )
);

console.log('TRegExp +flags:', regex `foo(bar)`.g);       // /foo(bar)/g
console.log('TRegExp +flags:', regex `foo(bar)`.i.m);     // /foo(bar)/im
console.log('TRegExp +flags:', regex `foo(bar)`.g.i._.y); // /foo(bar)/y 
//                                              ┗━━━━━┻━━━━ ( + 'g', + 'i', - 'gi', + 'y')

const group = regex `(?<foo>(:?bar)\d{2})`.g.i;
const t = `a bar12 bar0 bar13 bar-99 xyz BaR14 bar15 abc`;
console.log([...t.matchAll(group)].map(m => m.groups.foo));
// ["bar12", "bar13", "BaR14", "bar15"]
```

#### Option C: Use `Proxy()` for flags

You can proxy a "tagged template function" e.g. `regex()` and intercept any `get()` on it. Proxies can solve many *problems* but can also lead to great confusion. You can re-write the entire function and completely change the initial behavior.

```js
const escape = s => `${s}`.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

const _regex = (flags, {raw: [part, ...parts]}, ...subs) => new RegExp(
  subs.reduce(
    (result, sub, i) => `${result}${sub instanceof RegExp ? sub.source : escape(sub)}${parts[i]}`,
    part
  ),
  flags
); // ┗━━━ flags

const regex = new Proxy(_regex.bind(undefined, ''), {
  get: (target, property) => _regex.bind(undefined, property)
});


console.log('Proxy +flags:', regex.gi `foo(bar)`); // /foo(bar)/gi

const r = /(:?bar)\d{2}/; // matches: 'bar' + digit + digit ➜ 'bar12', 'abar123',..
const t = `(:?bar)\d{2}`; // template literal with regExp special chars

console.log('Proxy +flags:', regex.gi `(foo${r})`); // /(foo(:?bar)\d{2})/gi
console.log('Proxy +flags:', regex.gi `(foo${t})`); // /(foo\(:\?bar\)d\{2\})/gi
//                         flags ━┻━┛
```

---

#### More to read

- Article: [Easy Dynamic Regular Expressions with Tagged Template Literals and Proxies](https://lea.verou.me/2018/06/easy-dynamic-regular-expressions-with-tagged-template-literals-and-proxies/)
- GitHub: [icodeforlove/template-regexp](https://github.com/icodeforlove/template-regexp)
- Book: 2ality.com - [Using ES6 template strings for regular expressions](https://2ality.com/2012/12/template-strings-xregexp.html)
- Book: exploringjs.com - [Regular expressions (RegExp)](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_regexps.html)
- Book: exploringjs.com - [Using template literals and tagged templates](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_template-literals.html)

Comment: This reads more like a blog post than something suited for StackOverflow, and it doesn't seem to actually answer the question.