# Separating out Regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const url = "./index.js mongodb://localhost:27017/docs find betty";
```

`docs` is my database name

```
const db_name = ? 
const url = ?
```

How do I separate out the database name using regex in one variable, and the url in another?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template literal inside of the RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390873/template-literal-inside-of-the-regex)

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use group matches to define the characters you want to capture:

```js
const input = "./index.js mongodb://localhost:27017/docs find betty";

const regex = /(mongodb:\/\/\w*(\:\d{1,5})?\/(\w*))/;

const url = input.match(regex)[1];
const db_name = input.match(regex)[3];

console.log(url);
console.log(db_name);
```