# How To Use variable Inside Regex?

Tags: regex, reactjs

I'm working on a validation in react app That checks if the email address ends with (for ex: `google.com`, || `anything i pass to regex`)

```
So I need to pass a variable inside regex itself but i don't know how to do that
```

Here is what i did ---> this worked fine but it still static every time i want different domain i must change it here

```
export const emailAddress = (message = Strings.validationEmail) => new Validator({
  key: 'EMAIL',
  message,
  validator: value => /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@$gmail.com$/ig.test(`${value}`),
});
```

Now i want to replace google.com with any domain i provide to this function to be dynamic but the code below didn't work for me

```
export const emailAddressEndsWith = (domain = 'tvtc.com', message = Strings.validationEmailStartsWith) => new Validator({
  key: 'EMAIL',
  message: template(message)({ domain }),
  validator: value => new RegExp(`/^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@${domain}$/ig`).test(`${value}`),
});
```

Comment: Inside a `RegExp` constructor, you should not use a regex literal, use the pattern as the first argument, and flags as the second. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029142/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could u please write the answer here for me because i read it but i couldn't undrstand

Comment: No need to, see a more specific [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390873/template-literal-inside-of-the-regex), I have already answered such a question.