# Regex - Replace repeated character

Tags: regex

How can I replace some repeated characters using `regex`?

This is what I have so far:

```js
let message = "*test* _test_ ~test~"
    
    let replacedMessage = message
        .replace(/~(~*[^~\n]+~*)~/g, '<del>$1</del>')
        .replace(/_(_*[^_\n]+_*)_/g, '<em>$1</em>')
        .replace(/\*(\**[^*\n]+\**)\*/g, '<strong>$1</strong>')
        .replace(/\n/g, '<br>')

return replacedMessage
```

These are the desired results:

````
*test* => <strong> //Bold
_test_ => <em> //Italic
~test~ => <del> //Strikethrough
```test``` => <pre> //Monospaced
````

How can I do the ``` replacement to `<pre>`? I was unable to make this replacement with the regex.

Comment: You need to assign the result back to the variable. `message = message.replace...`

Comment: Silly error in my example, but the point is that I can't replace the ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the other regex patterns you're listing, it looks like you want to allow an unlimited number of the delimiter characters. For example, bold can be `*******bold this*******`. If you want this same behavior with ```` ``` ````, you can use:

```
.replace(/`{3}(`*[^`\n]+`*)`{3}/g, "<pre>$1</pre>")
```

Backtick within regex [does not conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830021/javascript-how-to-use-backtick-in-regular-expression) with template literals, so this will work fine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/syFB9o/3)

Comment: Awesome!! I should definitely study a little more regex =)

Comment: Any reason why you wrapped the capture group with `\`*`?

Comment: @Bren Only to match the same format as the other regexes in the question. I figured there was some reason the others had been written that way. As I mention in my answer, it allows for matching strings with unlimited numbers of backticks enclosing text that cannot contain backticks.

Answer (score 0):

````js
const message ="```test```" 
const regex = /`{3}([^`{3}]*)`{3}/g;
const result = message.replace(regex, "<pre>$1</pre>");
console.log(result);
````